# added a comma by mistake after a command - what did it do?

Tags: command-line

my question is (hopefully) not particularly important but I´d like to know the answer to it anyway.
I always like to learn something new.

I use **fish** as my default shell and wanted to type the following command:

```
bash -c 'cat /home/rosika/update.txt | grep "<"'
```

*After running a certain script beforehand* this command gives me list of changes after a recent system update.

Out of clumsiness I inadvertently added a comma at the end of the command:

```
bash -c 'cat /home/rosika/update.txt | grep "<"',
```

The intended command didn´t seem to have been executed at all and the return value  was "1":

```
echo $status # equals "echo $?" in bash

1
```

So I´d just like to know: what exactly did the added comma do?
Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

Many greetings.

Rosika

P.S.:

my system: Linux/Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS, 64 bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just grepped for the string `>,` instead of `>`

```
 ~> bash -xc 'echo foo | grep "foo"',
+ echo foo
+ grep foo,
```

The exit status was non-zero because grep did not find a match.

```
 ~> bash -c 'echo foo, | grep "foo"',
foo,
 ~> echo $status
0
```

Comment: Hi steeldriver: Thank you so much for your clarifying answer. I must admit this explanation wouldn´t have occurred to me as the comma in question was outside the quotation marks. Never would have guessed it might be part if the grep sequence. But I successfully could replicate your example-commands. Thanks once more and a Happy New Year.

Comment: @Rosika you're welcome - I guess the thing to remember is that the purpose of the quotes is to protect special character sequences from being interpreted by the shell(s). Since `,` is not special to either `fish` or `bash` it doesn't matter that it is unquoted.

Comment: Hi steeldriver O.K. I see now. That´s a fantastic explanation. Now I´ve definitively learnt something new. Thanks again so much. Your help is highly appreciated. Many greetings.